# Existence of Pre-Additive Topological categories

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Recall the notion of pre-addtive category and that of topological category (see Chapter 21 of The Joy of Cats). Well, my questions are:

1. Does there exist an example of pre-additive topological category?
2. If the answer to the previous question is affirmative, can you provide some reference on the general study of topological pre-additive categories, please?

Please, when answering, provide exhaustive point-by-point answers.

P.S. I'm extremely grateful to the user that provided in comments an answer concerning the fact that the category of binary relations is semiaddtive but not pre-additive.

Comment: The category of binary relations is semiadditive but not pre-additive; it's enriched over commutative monoids but not abelian groups.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your fundamental remark, it is like I thought. Well, what about the other questions?

Comment: Just to be clear (since I don't have a copy of The Joy of Cats), by "topological category" you mean https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category over $\text{Set}$? If so there are no such categories.

Comment: You can find the online version googling a few. But yes, the definition is that you found. Can you explain why there are no such categories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $U : C \to \text{Set}$ is a [topological concrete category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category) over $\text{Set}$ then in particular $U$ must have both a left and right adjoint (the "discrete topology" and "indiscrete topology") and so must preserve both limits and colimits; moreover (as stated by the nLab) $C$ is complete and cocomplete.  But if $C$ is a pre-additive category which has either all limits or all colimits then it must have a zero object (an object which is both initial and terminal), and $U$ applied to this object must be both the initial and terminal object of $\text{Set}$, which is impossible. So we conclude that no topological category over $\text{Set}$ can be pre-additive.

The natural question here is to ask for pre-additive topological categories over $\text{Ab}$ or similar, and here there are examples like topological abelian groups.

Comment: So in general I can ask for pre-additive topological categories over pointed categories, right?

Comment: @TheWanderer: you can try but there are further obstructions. If you want them over pointed sets then instead of arguing about zero objects we can argue about biproducts.

Comment: Yes, you're right. So in your edit, when you say Ab or similar, I think it is better to take abelian categories. Well, I don't know if a general study has been already carried out. And moreover I do not know how much interesting can be a so general analysis. I'm convincing that these categories are not so interesting.